# DevExpress Gridview FocusedRowHandle setter does not set new value

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

The setter for a DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView's FocusedRowHandle does not seem to set the value, it remains the same. Both the row with the old and new handle exist. I do not seem to get an exception either. Why does it not work? The grid is multiselect if that matters.

```
[...]
for (int i = this.GetMasterView().DataRowCount - 1; i > -1; i--)
                {
                    var row = this.GetMasterView().GetRow(i);
                    if (Equals(row, focused))
                    {
                        this.GetMasterView().FocusedRowHandle = i;
                        this.GetMasterView().ClearSelection();
                        this.GetMasterView().SelectRow(i);
                        ret = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
[...]

public static GridView GetMasterView(this GridControl gridControl)
        {
            return (GridView) gridControl.MainView;
        }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that your program actually makes it inside that if statement and that there is actually a selected row? I only ask because I've seen weird instances where because of manipulation in the code elsewhere, the row will end up deselected.

Comment: Yes, for example, the SelectRow works just fine (and as a result the focus and select become separated). SelectedRowsCount is 1.